# nginx referer check error: unknown directive "if($invalid_referer)"

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set specific request referer allowing in nginx.

nginx version is 1.12.2.

OS is amazon linux.

my conf file is like below.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    charset utf-8;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    valid_referers none server_names 123123123.com

    if($invalid_referer){
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        root   /home/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    ...etc...
```

error log is like below.

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($invalid_referer)" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:54
```

Could you help point out where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where nginx is telling you: line 54 of nginx.conf. Try this:

```
if ($invalid_referer) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Succeeded. error reason is nginx syntax...